# Bitbucket Pipelines - Multi Step Build Fails

Tags: node.js, angular, bitbucket, node-modules, bitbucket-pipelines

Okay, so I tried to pretty up my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file.  I have it working when I us the non-multi step one.  When I break everything up into multi step it fails on the `Karma/Jasmine Test:ci - Front-End` with a warning on of `"Error: Cannot find module 'karma-sonarqube-reporter' Require stack:..."`  I am assuming this has something to do with caches and modules not existing for each step?  I was trying `artifacts` and failed there too.  Here are the two examples I have.   Also, if there is any pointers on cleaning it up more as this is my first go, let me know - Thanks!

Single step

```
image: node:18.15.0
clone:
  depth: full
definitions:
  caches:
    sonar: ~/.sonar/cache
  steps:
    - step: &build-test-sonarcloud
        name: Build, test and analyze on SonarCloud
        caches:
          - node
          - sonar
        script:
          - echo "Installing Chrome"
          - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

          - echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
          - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

          - echo "Installing Angular CLI"
          - npm install -g @angular/cli

          - echo "Installing dependencies"
          - npm install

          - echo "Running Lint"
          - npm run lint

          - echo "Running Build"
          - npm run build

          - echo "Running Tests"
          - npm run test:ci

          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.4.0

    - step: &check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
        name: Check the Quality Gate on SonarCloud
        script:
          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.6

pipelines:
  branches:
    "**":
      - step: *build-test-sonarcloud
      - step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
  pull-requests:
    "**":
      - step: *build-test-sonarcloud
      - step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
```

And my hopes - multi:

```
image: node:18.15.0
clone:
  depth: full
definitions:
  caches:
    sonar: ~/.sonar/cache
  steps:
    - step: &Install-Chrome
        name: Install Chrome Browser For Test
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - echo "Installing Chrome"
          - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

          - echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
          - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

    - step: &Install-Angular-CLI
        name: Installing Angular CLI
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install -g @angular/cli

    - step: &Install-Dependencies
        name: Installing Dependencies (node_modules)
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install

    - step: &Linter
        name: Lint Code - Front-End
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm run lint

    - step: &Build-Project
        name: Build Project - Front-End
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm run build

    - step: &Tests
        name: Karma/Jasmine Test:ci - Front-End
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm run test:ci

    - step: &Sonarcloud-Test
        name: Analyze on SonarCloud
        caches:
          - node
          - sonar
        script:
          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.4.0

    - step: &Sonarcloud-Check-Quality-Gate
        name: Check the Quality Gate on SonarCloud
        script:
          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.6

pipelines:
  branches:
    "**": 
      - step: *Install-Chrome
      - step: *Install-Angular-CLI
      - step: *Install-Dependencies
      - step: *Linter
      - step: *Build-Project
      - step: *Tests
      - step: *Sonarcloud-Test
      - step: *Sonarcloud-Check-Quality-Gate
  pull-requests:
    "**": 
      - step: *Install-Chrome
      - step: *Install-Angular-CLI
      - step: *Install-Dependencies
      - step: *Linter
      - step: *Build-Project
      - step: *Tests
      - step: *Sonarcloud-Test
      - step: *Sonarcloud-Check-Quality-Gate
```

Comment: The image is wiped to the starting state between each step. This means you haven't run npm install/build before the tests. Same is for your Chrome installation, it's all lost after the step is complete. You could keep the npm stuff with artifacts/caching but it's kinda waste of time to run each step separately with how long it takes for the pipeline to boot up the image everytime